# Write byte array to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a file from Sharepoint on click of a link in ASPX. Facing some issue while writing the bytes to browser, the downloaded image file is partially loaded. when the file type is docx, the downloaded file is corrupt. Below is my code behind. Couldnt solve this though i came across many posts related to this.

```
using (var ffl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, file.ServerRelativeUrl))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                ffl.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.ContentType = "image/JPG";

                Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

Comment: Why do you whant to use the BinaryWrite method? You can easily use Response.Redirect(fileName) instead.

Comment: Where do you get `byteArray` from? Have you checked the length of that array?

Comment: the file is in sharepoint and i am trying to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the file is JPEG it can be jpg or png. Try using that.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/JPG"; 
or
Response.ContentType = "image/PNG";
```

Comment: That obviously not going to help as OP is able to see at least part of an image...

Comment: Content type is right, Also it works fine for text file. But images and docx getting corrupted.